# Differential Equation Issue

Tags: calculus, analysis

Let there be $r(t)$ a differentiable function (over one variable), and let us define $f$:

$$f(x,y) = x\cdot r\left(\frac{\partial y}{x}\right)$$

I need to find what expression this differential equation would hold (using only the function $f$ in it!)

$$x(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x})  + y (\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}) = ?$$

Thanks.

(My issue is getting rid of $r$ in the last equation to get something neat)